# Как добавить значение в элемент словаря,если внутри него список?

Tags: c#, словари

Есть словарь валют, содержащий цену валюты и другие дополнительные параметры на бирже.
Имеет такой вид

```
public Dictionary<string, Stack<Class_Currency>> CurrencyDictionary =new Dictionary<string, Stack<Class_Currency>>();
```

Я хочу, что б программа периодически делал запросы и вносила данные с стэк, при этом, что б последние данные были сверху и их можно было сразу взять.
В тоже время нужно хранить историю данных, что б произвести анализ по данным.
Как реализовать добаление в стек, находящийся в словаре?

Comment: `CurrencyDictionary[key].Push(new Class_Currency());` Вы уверены, что Вам нужен стэк?

Comment: @Igor  ну может и список. Надо просто брать последнее значение и расширять список при каждом запросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CurrencyDictionary[key].Push(new Class_Currency());
```

или для `Dictionary<string, List<Class_Currency>>`:

```
CurrencyDictionary[key].Add(new Class_Currency());
```